# Getting error when calling Web Service

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I am trying to call web service using PHP/SOAP, Here is the code but i don't know what am i doing wrong?

```
$client = new SoapClient(null, array('exceptions' => true, 'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'location' => `https://services.acxiom.com/risk-findpeople0003/1.0?WSDL`, 'uri' => `https://services.acxiom.com/risk-findpeople0003/1.0?WSDL`, 'login' => 'LOGIN_VAL', 'password' => 'PASS_VAL',));
```

Below is the error i am getting:

```
SoapFault: Endpoint
{`http://findpeople0003.riskapi.acxiom.com/risk-findpeople0003/1.0`} RiskFindPeople0003BeanPort
does not contain operation meta data for:
{`https://services.acxiom.com/risk-findpeople0003/1.0?WSDL`}getFindPeople
in `SoapClient->__call()`
```

Do you know why this is coming?
Thank You!

Comment: Please use some code tags and clean this up a bit, then we will try to help you.

Comment: @Phillip - I think now its much better.

Comment: try $client = new SoapClient(wsdlUrl, array(options)); and also show us how ur calling the web service.

Comment: I had already tried it like this:  

    $client = new SoapClient('https://services.acxiom.com/risk-findpeople0003/1.0?WSDL',  
    array('login' => 'LOGIN_VAL', 'password' => 'PASS_VAL',))  

but it gives me new error:  

    Warning: SoapClient::SoapClient(): SSL: Connection reset by peer in webserviceFindPeople() (line 31...  

    SoapFault: SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'https://services.acxiom.com/risk-findpeople0003/1.0?WSDL' : Premature end of data in tag definitions line 1 in SoapClient->SoapClient() (line 31 ...

Comment: Replies are still appreciable.